# linux crontab + add shell syntax to crontab

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, rhel, cron

we add the following line to `crontab`  ( the script - test.bash should run every min )

```
* * * * * root  [[ -f test.bash ]] && /tmp/test.bash
```

the script is like that

```
more  test.bash

#!/bin/bash

echo TEST >/tmp/file.txt
```

but we not see any content on the `/tmp/file.txt` even after couple min

what is wrong in the following `crontab` syntax ?

```
* * * * * root  [[ -f test.bash ]] && /tmp/test.bash
```

we also try

```
* * * * * root  [[ -f test.bash ]] && bash /tmp/test.bash
```

but still /tmp/file.txt file is empty

Comment: Why did you put `root` in there?

Comment: What crontab did you use? Did you edit `/etc/crontab` or did you run `crontab -e` as a user? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Did you check the logs (`/var/log/syslog`)? Search for `CRON` and check the errors thereafter.

Comment: By default, `[[ -f test.bash ]]` tests for the existence of `test.bash` in root's home directory (usually `/root`). Is this intended?

Comment: Alternately: `* * * * * bash -c 'script="/tmp/test.bash"; [[ -f "$script" ]] && source "$script"'`

Answer (score -2):

The `crontab` `command` parameter is NOT `bash`. The `command` is simply passed to the`execve` system call without interpretation. Do your `bash`isms (like `[[`) in your `bash` script, and not in the `crontab` `command` parameter.

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem either.

Comment: @jesse_b what do you mean? There were two problems: 1st, the OP apparently used a user crontab (`crontab -e`) but used the format for `/etc/crontab` where you must specify a user name. In addition, the command is using bashisms and AFAIK cron will run them using `sh`, not `bash`. Of the two, this seems like the more serious error since the use of `root` is fine in `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: @terdon: Apparently it wasn't because OPs issue went away when they removed root.  Also I don't necessarily recommend it but if /bin/sh is bash it will most likely accept bashisms.  Additionally this doesn't provide an alternative.

Comment: Simply place `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the beginning of the `crontab`.

Comment: A recent (not very recent) extension/improvements to the `crontab` processing method. User `root` (`UID=0`), using `/etc/crontab`, specifies a `username` to run the `cron` job as. For parsing reasons, the `username` is placed after the <periodicity specification> and the `command`. Non-`root` users are not allowed to do this, and use older format `crontab` files (<periodicity specification> `command` in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`. But one shouldn't care where `crontab` files are kept,  and access user `crontab`s with `crontab -e`.